# iterate over a groupby field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a publicly available dataset in pandas which has some air quality statistics by each state of USA.

I load he dataset in a pandas dataframe and use `groupby` to group things by the `state`. So something like:

```
import pandas as pd
poll = pd.read_csv(`dataset.csv')
poll = poll.groupby(['State', 'Date Local']).mean()
ds_gb_state = poll.groupby(level='State')
```

Printing this gives something like:

```
                        V1         V2          V3        V4
State      Date Local
Alabama    2013-12-01  37.000000  24.000000   1.000000   6.000000
           2013-12-02  30.000000  12.000000   3.000000   6.000000
           2013-12-03  21.000000  11.000000   3.000000   3.000000
           2013-12-04  18.000000  13.000000   1.000000   2.000000
           2013-12-05  15.000000  13.000000   1.000000   2.000000
Alaska     2014-07-01   4.000000  16.000000   6.000000   3.000000
           2014-07-02   4.000000  15.000000   6.000000   3.000000
           2014-07-03   6.000000  19.000000  13.000000   3.000000
```

My question is simple. Using this `ds_gb_state` object, how can  I find the names of all the states? In this object the columns are the `V1, V2, V3 and V4` and I can access them fine but is it  possible to enumerate over all the states or find the minimum and maximum dates from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main components of a `pandas.MultiIndex` are the `levels` and `labels` attributes.  When one is constructed, the `levels` should be a `FrozenList` of `pandas.Index` objects.  What's more is that those `Index` objects should be unique (this can be intentionally broken but is usually `True`).  As such, you can retrieve the unique values with

```
ds_gb_state.index.levels[0]

Index(['Alabama', 'Alaska'], dtype='object', name='State')
```

Assuming the second level is of dtype datetime

```
ds_gb_state.index.set_levels(pd.to_datetime(ds_gb_state.index.levels[1]), 1, True)
```

We can do the same trick to get the minimum.

```
ds_gb_state.index.levels[1].min()

Timestamp('2013-12-01 00:00:00')
```

---

Though I believe [@yatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047697/2336654) is completely deserving.  It deserves a comparison

The method `get_level_values` utilizes the `levels` and `labels` attributes and is equivalent to this

```
ds_gb_state.index.get_level_values(0)

Index(['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alaska',
       'Alaska', 'Alaska'],
      dtype='object', name='State')
```

and

```
ds_gb_state.index.levels[0][ds_gb_state.index.labels[0]]

Index(['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alaska',
       'Alaska', 'Alaska'],
      dtype='object', name='State')
```

So to get unique values, pandas has to take already unique values slice in order to produce potentially non-unique values only to go through the trouble of making them unique again.  I suggest skipping the unnecessary step.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find the names of all the states?

You can use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
# Index(['Alabama', 'Alaska'], dtype='object')
```

> is it possible to find the minimum and maximum dates from this object?

Similarly for the dates:

```
df.index.get_level_values(1).map(pd.to_datetime).min()
# Timestamp('2013-12-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work for a dataframe object buut what would be the equivalant of a dataframegroupby object? I am very new to pandas. Currently, I get: Cannot access attribute 'index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method\

Comment: This works for a `MultiIndex` dataframe, which is the structure of the object after aplying a groupby

Comment: Thank you. I needed to add the size() method... So something like: ds_gb_state = poll.groupby(level='State').size(). Is that the right way to do this?

Comment: Note that by adding `reset_index()` you will have a single index again

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote/accept if it helped :) @luca

Comment: I upvoted but have to wait a few minutes to a ccept. You were too fast ;-)